# Unable to determine why form won't submit

Tags: angularjs

I've created a basic angular form and can't determine why it's not submitting.

http://contact-info.checkoutbiblebowl.com/

The form validation is valid and it still won't submit.  I feel like I've overlooked something silly, but have looked at this over the last few days and can't figure out what it is.  Any suggestions?

```
<form method='post' action='' name='form' novalidate ng-controller="myController">
    <div class="row form">
        <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-row">
            <label class="form-label" style='margin-top: 20px'>Name</label>
            <div class="form-item">
                <div style="float: left">
                    First<br/>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="firstName" name="firstName" class="small" style="width: 200px" maxlength="32" required>
                    <div ng-cloak ng-show="form.firstName.$error.required" class="required">First name is required</div>
                </div>
                <div style="float: left; margin-left: 1em">
                    Last<br/>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="lastName" name="lastName" class="small" style="width: 200px" maxlength="32" required>
                    <div ng-cloak ng-show="form.lastName.$error.required" class="required">Last name is required</div>
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-row">
            <button ng-disabled="!form.$valid" type="submit" class="btn" ng-click="debug()">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**My Controller:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('contact', []).
    controller('myController', function ($scope) {
        $scope.debug = function () {
            console.log($scope.form);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ng-click="debug()" ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to specify the action explicitly, not with an empty string otherwise angular will prevent the submission.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:form

like so:
http://plnkr.co/edit/WtP03BFVyEsnOqf3n8a4?p=preview